# Itextsharp siging xfa form field is not found

Tags: itext

I have an xfa form created with adobe lifecycle designer.  I can successfully fill the form, however it has signature fields I am unable to sign.  When signing the field the code errors saying field is not found (I have the correct field name), however if i use adobe reader and sign the form, I can then resign it using the exact same code.  I am using the example from Digital Signatures for PDF Documents by Bruno Lowagie -Sequential Signatures. Do I need to activate the signature field?  Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 0):

Signing XFA forms is described in PAdES-5 and although you forgot to share any code, you are probably adding a signature as described in PAdES-2 or PAdES-3. In the past, we have implemented PAdES-5, but we never promoted that functionality because as far as I know, Adobe itself didn't follow the PAdES-5 standard. In other words: our code followed the standard, but it was useless because no one else implemented the standard. With ISO-32000-2, XFA has been deprecated which means that all further investment in XFA is money thrown away. It is surprising that you are still using XFA because the deprecation of XFA has been communicated many years ago.

Allow me to disect your question:

- When you search for the signature field with iText, that field is not found. That is normal: the form is a pure XFA form. There is no AcroForm field to be found; the field is expressed in XML. iText only looks at AcroForm signature fields.
- You can sign the document using Adobe Reader. Indeed, Adobe has implemented a way to sign XFA forms that is somewhat different than PAdES-5. During the signature process, an AcroForm signature field is created.
- After you have signed the document using Adobe Reader, iText can see the field. Indeed, since Adobe Reader added an AcroForm signature field, iText can now detect it.

What are your options? If you can abandon XFA, do so. For instance: you could create forms based on the AcroForm technology instead of XFA forms. If that's not an option, you could flatten the form before signing it. That way, you will have an ordinary PDF to which you can add AcroForm signature fields.

If none of the above options work for you, your only option is to stick with Adobe software. That means buying licenses for Adobe LiveCycle ES. Be aware however that XFA is legacy software. If I were your CTO, I would not approve the use of XFA.

Comment: Thank you very much, answers it perfectly.  I have spent many hours trying  to solve this, I will try some of your suggestions.